# Is it accurate to consider a struct to be a data type?

Tags: c++, c, types

Based on my understanding of data types: computers can only store 0s and 1s, it cannot store a negative number,  a real number, a character, etc. So data types were invented to represent (encode) each of these types of data as a set of 0s and 1s and then decode it when needed.

But what about a struct:

```
struct Student
{
    int age;
    float gpa;
};

Student s1; s1.age = 17; s1.gpa = 3.42;
Student s2; s2.age = 16; s2.gpa = 3.64;
```

This just seems like a facility so I don't have to write:

```
int student1_age = 17;
float student1_gpa = 3.42;

int student2_age = 16;
float student2_gpa = 3.64;
```

So is it accurate to consider a `Student` to be a data type the same way we consider a `float` to be a data type?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure

Comment: yes you can represent variables separately like that. But you don't want to use it when you need to declare hundreds of structs with tens or hundreds of members inside. That's also a pain when you need to pass it to functions

Comment: @Igor Isn´t this yet another thing? `int` or `float` as data types are not comparable to linked lists or B-Trees.

Comment: Regarding the question in your title, it depends on your language. Please pick one, because C and C++ are very different in this regard.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Do you mean different in the way we create a struct? (i.e. in C: struct Student s1;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on my understanding of data types: computers can only store 0s
>   and 1s, it cannot store a negative number, a real number, a character,
>   etc. So data types were invented to represent (encode) each of these
>   types of data as a set of 0s and 1s and then decode it when needed.

Correct. The difference between eg. `int` and `float` is only how to interpret the bits (and depending on the HW, how many bit it needs). For representations of negative numbers, decimal numbers etc., there are multiple known possibilites and processors supporting calculations on these data formats, but that´s another topic.

And if a defined `struct` is a data type depends on the level of abstraction (and a bit on opinion too). In C code, it´s a data type (something to define what new variables are); but not when talking about eg. CPU internals. ...

Answer (score 2):

structure is a collection of items of different data-types. So yes a `structure` is also a data-type, which is user-defined.

But the other part where you talk about negative values can't be represented and all. Negative numbers are available in c that's why we have `signed` integers.

Characters can also be stored using a data-type `char`

`structure` is a facility to group things like you have shown.

I hope this is a typo but just fixing it. There should `;` at the end of the structure definition.

Comment: I meant we can't write inside of a computer's memory: -00101101, we can only write: 00101101.

Comment: @joseph_m That's usually done with the most significant bit to indicate a positive (`0`) or negative (`1`) number.

Comment: @joseph_m Your interpratation is wrong , if you want to have a negative integer just go use it like `int i = -10;` where do you see a actual need to have `-0010` something like this

Comment: @joseph_m yes we can't write -00101101, that's why people invented sign-magnitude or ones'/two's complement to represent signed numbers

Answer (score 1):

`int` & `float` *arithmetic* types are collectively called as *Scalar Types*. Where as `struct` types are called *Aggregate Types*, which allocates sequentially a set of member objects which possibly can have distinct data types. Hence `struct` is nothing less than a data type similar to standard object types.

Answer (score 0):

**Structures** are the data types which are used to integrate different data typed members in it. And declare all the members at the same time with the declaration of the struct object. You can also declare structs in other structs. Like

```
struct movie
{
  string name;
  string release_date;
};

struct movie_store
{
  movie *ptr;
}
```

Here I have used the *ptr whose data type movie which is a struct, **so yes struct can be considered as a data type**

Answer (score 0):

```
struct X{
     char a, b;
     int count;
     float n;
};

struct book;
```

So the answer is yes. Struct is a data type that you define

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> In computer science and computer programming, a data type or simply type is a classification identifying one of various types of data, such as real, integer or Boolean, that determines the possible values for that type; the operations that can be done on values of that type; the meaning of the data; and the way values of that type can be stored. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type))

In other words, a data type tells computer how to interpret(explain) a set of given data, and since  the same data can be interpreted differently (and correctly) in some cases, data types are crucial. To some extent the relationship between data and data type likes the one between `HTML` and `CSS`: the former is the **Content**, the latter specifies the **Presentation** (what will we see when looking at it).

So a struct is definitely a data type, for it conveys the information we can use to interpret a set of data.

One difference between structs/arrays and basic types (`int`, `float`, `boolean`, `char`, etc.) is that a struct/array can also tell us the relationship of basic type(s) inside them. All variables inside a struct is related to the struct and should be treated as a whole. An array tells you that all its atoms are parallel. But a variable of basic type just means there stores a stand-alone, simple mathematical or logical value.